# Go Static Files Serve giving 404 in Linux

Tags: go, mux

I have a Simple Web Server in Go as below:

```
func webServerWay() {

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    
    //File Upload Code
    r.HandleFunc("/upload", uploadFile).Methods("POST")
    
    //Test Message
    r.HandleFunc("/test", test).Methods("GET")

    r.PathPrefix("/site/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/site/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("site"))))


if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8010", r); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

Simple Test Function looks as below: It's A Simple Function to see if the endpoint is reachable.

```
func test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Welcome it Works!")
}
```

Site Structure is:

```
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── site
    ├── dist
    └── index.html
```

The Application Works Perfectly in my local dev environment i.e. Mac OS:

```
Ajay@apples-MacBook-Air:/$ curl localhost:8010/test
Welcome it Works!
Ajay@apples-MacBook-Air:/$ curl localhost:8010/site/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>gAnalytics</title>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
  <script defer src="./dist/appXYZ.min.js"></script></head>
</html>
```

But When I Create a Build for Linux(Ubuntu 20.04)x64

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=386 go build -o gApp24v1.linux main.go
```

And run the code in Linux:

```
sudo ./gApp24v1.linux
```

The Static Site Serving Doesn't Work, But I can reach the Test Endpoint:

```
root@gapp24:/home/ajay/app# curl localhost:8010/test
Welcome it Works!
root@gapp24:/home/ajay/app#  curl localhost:8010/site/
404 page not found
```

I have tried multiple ways of code in static file handler seeing other answers and reading the document but it works in my macOS and not my Linux Machine.

Any Suggestions!

Also the netstat in my Linux(Ubuntu machine) is below:

```
root@gapp24:/home/ajay/app# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      671/vsftpd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      547/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      704/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::8010                 :::*                    LISTEN      1167/./gApp24v1.lin 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      704/sshd: /usr/sbin
```

Comment: is your static file included in the right directory in linux? is it in `/home/ajay/app` directory where you seem to run the binary from?

Comment: Hey @WishwaPerera: Moving Static Site directory with the build works!

But when I move the build file around(Using `go build main.go`=> result into `main` build file) my local computer then by just serving the build file in any folder with `./main` without the site directory I still get the server running properly?

But in other OS I need to move the static site with the go build file!
Is this something to do with GOPATH? But my GOPATH doesn't include my current project directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Deploying the build file, the respective static files need to be also moved accordingly:

Here `gApp24v1.linux` is the build for Linux. The static files containing folder `site` needs to be also placed in the respective path:

```
.
├── gApp24v1.linux
└── site
    ├── dist
    │   ├── appXYZ.min.js
    └── index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving  Static Site directory, you can use this repo `https://github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata` to zip your static file into manageable Go source code.

Comment: Hey Alex, We can put it in GitHub but these are build files, also do every time my app starts, it loads the code from Github if we do it this way, later on, will it create the performance issue if we want to scale the operations?